# how to define my 3rd visible cell as variable in column B

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I would like to define the variable of the 3rd visible cell in my filtered column B.
The position of my 3rd visible cell can change according to the value selected in my filter.

[image]

In my example, the 3rd cell is B16, but it is not always this value. If I manage to define the variable of my 3rd visible cell in column B, I would be able to change B16 in my VBA code by this variable.

```
Sub jfdjdgfjg()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveCell.Formula = "= SUM(B16:B" & LastRow & ")" 'Sum until lastrow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one method

```
Option Explicit

Sub thirdviscell()
Dim LRow As Long, i As Long, counter As Long
Dim thirdcell As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LRow 'assuming a header row not to be counted
        If .Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then counter = counter + 1
        If counter = 3 Then 
            Set thirdcell = .Cells(i, "B")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With

MsgBox "The third visible cell's address is " & thirdcell.Address(0,0), vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot to all of you, it works well, @Tim, I had to change a bit your code to adapt it to my macro, but it works well...

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the visible cells and count them like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Example()
    MsgBox GetFilteredRowNumber(ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"), 3)
End Sub

Private Function GetFilteredRowNumber(ByRef r As Range, ByRef num As Long) As Long
    Dim aCell As Range, i As Long
    GetFilteredRowNumber = 0
    For Each aCell In Intersect(r.Parent.UsedRange, r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)).Cells
        i = i + 1
        If i = num Then
            GetFilteredRowNumber = aCell.Row
            Exit For
        End If
    Next aCell
End Function
```